# Can a specialized parametric class/trait extend another trait?

Tags: scala, generics

Suppose I have two traits, `Foo` and `Bar[T]`, one of them parametric. Is there any way to declare that certain parameterizations of `Bar` are `Foo`s (e.g., `Bar[String]<:Foo`)?

Obviously I could create a third trait `Baz extends Bar[String] with Foo`, but in my actual use case there there are more than two relevant traits, leading to unfavorable combinatorics, and this also confuses pattern matching on sealed traits.

Comment: Can you modify `Foo`? Also, what problems are you trying to solve? Can you show us a more complete example?

Comment: You can define implicit `implicit val ev: Bar[String] <:< Foo = null` (although this is weaker than `Bar[String] <: Foo`). Whether this is enough depends on your actual use case. You should provide more details.

Comment: In Dotty for trait `Foo` and **type** `Bar[T]` we can write: `trait Foo`
  `type Foo1[A] = A match {
    case String => Foo;
    case _ => Any
  }`
  `type Bar[A] <: Foo1[A]`